# Unable to add large text in database field

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried varchar(5000), text, mediumtext, longtext but all in vain.
if i add the data from phpmyadmin it is added succesfully but through query it adds only if i give data less than 200 characters if the data is more than 200 characters the whole query won't execute.

I am not getting any errors in my code.

```
$newsTitle = $_POST['newsTitle'];
$newsType = $_POST['newsType'];
$newsDescription = $_POST['newsDescription'];

$target_dir = "../images/news/".$newsType."/";
$target_file = $target_dir .$adminId.rand(5,100)."_". basename($_FILES["newsImage"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["newsImage"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["newsImage"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["newsImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["newsImage"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

$newsImage = $target_file;

$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");



mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `news`(`addedBy`, `title`, `type`, `description`, `image`, `datetime`, `comments`, `views`)
VALUES ($adminId,'$newsTitle','$newsType','".$_POST['newsDescription']."','$newsImage','$datetime',0,0)");
```

Comment: could you post your code in here?

Comment: so your problem in the query, or in the php execution of it.

Comment: i have added my code here...

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "the whole query won't execute"? Do you mean that the query is returning an error? are you certain that the code execution reaches the `mysqli_query` statement?